# select rows where not in multiple columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, where-in

I have a following result set:

```
request_id  |  p_id
66          |  10
66          |  10
66          |  10
66          |  22
66          |  22
76          |  23
76          |  24
```

I am trying to select rows that `excludes` records with certain combination values:

```
request_id   |   product_id
66           |   10
76           |   23
```

So the output result set should contain only these records:

```
66          |  22
66          |  22
76          |  24
```

I tried doing:

```
select * from `table` 
where request_id NOT IN (66, 76) AND product_id NOT IN (10, 22)
```

But this gives me empty resultset.

How do I exclude just the combination of those two values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=069ae8b9cd6526ce36ed98d194b82633)**

```
select * from `table` 
where (request_id, p_id) NOT IN ((66, 10),(76,23))
```

OUTPUT:

```
request_id  p_id
66          22
66          22
76          24
```

Comment: And what if the second table will contain `(67, 11)`?

Comment: @SeaSharp then that wil be returned in query output.

Comment: @TechnoCrat. This query is not general.

Answer (score 2):

Try use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.request_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT r_id 
    FROM TABLE2
)
AND TABLE1.p_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT p_id 
    FROM TABLE2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a better way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.request_id = TABLE2.r_id
                AND TABLE1.p_id = TABLE2.p_id
WHERE TABLE2.p_id IS NULL
```